# How to use Bundle outState?

Tags: android, bundle

Im looking for good information on how to use the bundle to save and reload a state. If anyone could provide me with good example please do. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Rotation) is a set of projects by Mark Murphy dealing with rotation, which uses outState extensively. The projects should stand on their own (projects one through five get progressively more detailed) but can also be accompanied by his [books.](http://commonsware.com/books) I am not a salesman, but either way that should help you out.

Comment: Thats funny, because i actually am subscribed to his warescription